# Is there a way to populate a table using powerapps that is a "new" product

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I built a powerapps app and I've setup it to connect to MySQL (a database that is locally hosted that is connected to a warehouse). After doing research, I was searching for a way to input new products into it.

We process containers, so when there is an error with a container (extra or less product), they are able to log it but it is connected directly to the database.

Is there a way for them to log when there is a new product, that shouldn't be in that container, but is? It shouldn't be connected to the database, but it should output the product/quantity into an excel table that's connected to onedrive (it's all setup)

I was stuck with this issue for quite a while

```
Patch(
    Product,
    Defaults(Product),
    {
        FirstName: FirstName,
        LastName: LastName,
        AuditDate: Value(Today()),
        Order: Gallery2.Selected.order_id,
        Carton: Gallery2.Selected.cntnr_id,
        Zone: Gallery2.Selected.zone_num,
        Date: Gallery2.Selected.shift_date,
        Customer: DataCardValue9.Text,
        'Product (Product)': Gallery2.Selected.sku,
        Location: Gallery2.Selected.loc_alias,
        OP: Gallery2.Selected.user_id,
        QRequested: Gallery2.Selected.quantity,
        Actual: Value(TextInput1_2.Text),
        CartonType: Gallery2.Selected.cntnr_type
    });
Set(TotalUnits, TotalUnits + Abs(Gallery2.Selected.quantity - TextInput1_2));
Reset(TextInput1_2);
Reset(TextInput2_2)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to have an Excel file with a table created, with the rows already named. After create a connection to your OndeDrive. I'll leave you a link to a video that does what you need: [Here](https://youtu.be/-Z_13J02RPU)

It's Shane Young, a Microsoft MVP